# Automating code creation based on conventions

Tags: visual-studio, automation, scaffolding

I am frequently creating many classes such as `Builders`, `Commands` and `Queries`. Each one has a convention where the concrete lives in the project structure and where the interface (usually one level higher) lives.

Is there a way to automate creating these sorts of files these days, if so, what are my options...

If I have this structure `(= Project, + Folder, - File)`;-

```
Solution
 = Web
   + Controllers
 = CommandQuery
   + Commands
     + Interfaces
       - IMyCommand.cs
     - MyCommand.cs
   + Queries
     + Interfaces
       - IMyQuery.cs
     - MyQuery.cs
 = Builders
   + Interfaces
     - IMyBuilder.cs
   - MyBuilder.cs
```

I'd like to basically use a command, macro, template or scaffolding mechanism to say "make me a builder" and it'd generate me the appropriate class and interface in the correct location.

I do have access to both resharper and code rush also but would prefer to avoid these. I am not averse to using the command line if there's appropriate tools in this area also.

Comment: Do you know what Code generation with T4 templates are? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb126445.aspx I use them for the exact same goal as you do.

Comment: I know of them, can't say I have used them much. I'll take another look.